# Unexpected linebreak after avatar

Tags: bug, design

On Samsung's browser called "Internet", the name, rep and badge-summary is not shown on the right side of the avatar, but below. This happens on all the regular pages and the topuser pages, like so:

[image: Topuser's page on "Internet" browser]

This has changed some months ago. Maybe at the same time when the big numbers of the topusers page were replaced by smaller ones.